# Are the findbugs rules that come with sonarqube findbugs plugin same as the actual findbugs rules

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs, rules

Are the findbugs rules that come with sonarqube find-bugs plugin and the actual findbugs rules that come when findbugs is installed in eclipse one and the same.

If not , is there any way to use the actual findbugs ruleset in sonarqube instead of using the ruleset that comes with findbugs sonarqube plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FindBugs Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs) calls external **FindBugs analyzer** - it means that they are the same rules.

[image: Version Matrix]

Read more on https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs#compatibility